# Pandas truncate the first 5 characters of a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In my dataframe, I have a numeric field CLIENT_ID, and I need to truncate it by removing the first 5 characters..so if the field is 51000222, I want 222.

I do:

```
df['CLIENT_ID'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.slice(5, -1))
```

But I get error: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'CLIENT_ID': [51000222, 456]})
```

you can do

```
df['CLIENT_ID'].astype(str).str[5:]
0    222
1       
Name: CLIENT_ID, dtype: object
```

Second row is used to show what happens with too short IDs

Comment: Thank you so much. I was honestly losing it over this rather simple problem.